# Binary Search Tree insertion by recursive function can't access node by root

Tags: c++, recursion, struct, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a code for binary search tree using struct in C. I thought of making two separate struct called 'tree' and 'node'. Then I create a pointer object of root. I plan to link all node to root's object sequentially. But when I try to go to node from root's object compiler shows error.
My code is like :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
}*new_node ;
struct tree{
    int count;
    struct node* p;
}*root ;
void create_root(){
    root = (tree *) malloc(sizeof(tree));
    root->count=0;
    root->p=NULL;
}
void insert_node(tree *root){
    if(root->p == NULL and root->count==0){
        root->p = new_node;
        root->count++;
        return;
    }
    else if(root->p->left==NULL and root->p->right==NULL){
        if(root->p->data > new_node->data){
            root->p->left =  new_node;
        }
        else if(root->p->data <= new_node->data){
            root->p->right =  new_node;
        }
        root->count++;
        return;
    }
    else{
        if(root->p->data <= new_node->data){
            return insert_node(root->p->right);
        }
        if(root->p->data > new_node->data){
            return insert_node(root->p->left);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    create_root();
    new_node = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data=321;
    new_node->left=NULL;
    new_node->right=NULL;
    insert_node(*root);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler shows error like:

```
/home/ahashans/Documents/bst_new.cpp||In function ‘void 
insert_node(tree*)’:|
/home/ahashans/Documents/bst_new.cpp|37|error: cannot convert ‘node*’ to 
‘tree*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void insert_node(tree*)’|
/home/ahashans/Documents/bst_new.cpp|37|error: return-statement with a 
value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]|
/home/ahashans/Documents/bst_new.cpp|40|error: cannot convert ‘node*’ to 
‘tree*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void insert_node(tree*)’|
 /home/ahashans/Documents/bst_new.cpp|40|error: return-statement with a 
 value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]|
 /home/ahashans/Documents/bst_new.cpp||In function ‘int main()’:|
 /home/ahashans/Documents/bst_new.cpp|51|error: cannot convert ‘tree’ to 
 ‘tree*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void insert_node(tree*)’|
  ||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) 
  ===|
```

Comment: Did you even read error message?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm a little bit rusty on struct and pointer.

Comment: It has nothing to do with struct or pointer. You try to assign a value of `tree*` type to the variable of `node*` type. They are different types, how do you expect compiler to convert one to another? This is basic stuff, I'd suggest you read a C++ book before you start diving into binary trees, recursion and pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally have the signature of your insert_node as

```
tree* insert_node(node *new_node, tree* mytree)
```

which means that please insert new_node in mytree and return a new tree with inserted node.

Comment: the compiler still shows error when executing:                                    return insert_node(new_node, root->p->right);

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib: you need to write a code for this method. It wont automatically do anything! Also in your error case you are passing node pointer to the function. it shud be tree pointer instead.